# Is it possible to record the screen and Audio on a Raspberry Pi 4 model B

Tags: raspbian, pi-4, raspberry-pi-desktop, screen-recorder

I wanna record my screen and audio, Is It Possible? how to do that?
I use Raspberry Pi 4 Model B.

I still new, I hope you can help.
thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Kazam is another great screen recorder. It's graphical, easy to use, and has a ton of features.

To install it:

1) Open a terminal (click on the raspberry icon in the task bar, go down to Accessories, and then click on Terminal)

2) Type in `sudo apt-get update` then `sudo apt-get install kazam`

3) To run it, you can launch it from the taskbar (you'll find it under the raspberry icon in a submenu) or type in `kazam` from the terminal.

[image: Kazam screenshot]

Comment: I follow steps that you make it above, and I got an error like this: ```pi@raspberrypi:~ $ kazam
/usr/bin/kazam:32: PyGIWarning: Gtk was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.``` @user96931

Answer (score 2):

`recordMyDesktop` is here for you. It captures what you are watching on the screen and also saves all audio input/output.

You can use it by the terminal and also it has a GUI like the image below:

[image]

Update repository:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Install the package:

```
sudo apt-get install recordmydesktop
```

Start recording/capturing:

```
recordmydesktop myCapture.ogv
```

To stop the process hit `Ctrl + C` and then it will save a `.ogv` file in the current path.

---

More configuration on [man page](http://recordmydesktop.sourceforge.net/manpage.php) of this package.

Comment: That didn't work well for me. Although I was able to record the screen, the video ended up with a lot of pink added, not with the actual screen colors... also, I had to disable sound, because the sound card was not recognized...

Answer (score 2):

[Vokoscreen](https://linuxecke.volkoh.de/vokoscreen/vokoscreen.html) works well on Raspberry Pi OS.

```
sudo apt install vokoscreen
```

VLC was not able to play the default format MKV recordings Vokoscreen makes for me, but you can play them with `ffplay` (part of [FFmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/)):

```
ffplay -i ~/Videos/screencast.mkv
```